# Drupal namespace issue

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, namespaces

After migration to the new server **sometimes** i run into the issue:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
>   Collaboration\\getAllResources() in....

But in my code i can see following line:

> $tmp = \Collaboration\getAllResources();

I tried to use "use" statement, but it did not help.
I also tried all possible solutions I found.

I'm using:
**PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11**
**Drupal    7.39**

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the xautoload (http://drupal.org/project/xautoload) module to help with autoloading. Also try to use files[] array in your .info file -

```
...
files[] = DdFactory.inc
files[] = ArticleManager.inc
...
```